# Multiprocessing on python 3.10 appending to the same list

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm currently trying to learn how to use multiprocessing on python. Moreover I want to apply multiprocessing on a code of mine.

I have read other questions on the subject but the solutions on those questions did not work on my environment (maybe because something has changed with python 3.10)

My code looks like:

```
def obtenern2():
        A = []
        for d in days:
            aux = dfhabil[dfhabil["day"] == d]
            n2 = casosn(aux,2)
            aml = ExportarMODml(n2)
            adl = ExportarMODdl(n2)
            A.append(aml)
            A.append(adl)
        return pd.concat(A)

B = obtenern2()
```

where "ExportarMODml" or "ExportarMODdl" takes the dataframe "n2" and perform some calculations returning a dataframe (so "A" is actually a list of dataframes).

I think that "ExportarMODml" and "ExportarMODdl" could be process in parallel, but I dont know how to append the resulting dataframes to the same list without causing corruption or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pattern that you could probably adapt to your requirements.

We have two functions ExportarMODml and ExportarMODdl. Each function takes a dictionary as its only argument and returns a DataFrame.

These can be executed in parallel and a concatenation of the returned DataFrames can be achieved thus:

```
from pandas import concat, DataFrame
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def ExportarMODml(d):
    return DataFrame(d)

def ExportarMODdl(d):
    return DataFrame(d)

def main():
    d = {'a': [1,2], 'b': [3,4]}

    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as ppe:
        futures = [ppe.submit(func, d) for func in (ExportarMODml, ExportarMODdl)]
        df = concat([future.result() for future in futures])
        print(df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

Comment: Hi, Pingu. I've tried to adapt your proposal, but I'm getting : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apply'. Instead of a dictionary my iterable "d" is a list with a dataframe for each day. Any clues?